# Thoughts on this Vertical Align <span> hack

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm building a mobile app using the [Ionic Framework](http://ionicframework.com/). My app's Header Title is using a custom font, loaded via `@font-face`.

I have three examples of the header below. The top being the default, and the last two using my custom font.

[image: Ionic Header example]

You can see by default (HELVETICA TITLE) everything is vertically center. Ionic uses the line-height trick.

The second header in purple is with the custom font applied and it's obviously off centered.

The third was accomplished by wrapping the title in a `<span>` and splitting the font style.

Is this an acceptable practice? Anything I should be concerned about? Any way to accomplish the vertical align without the additional `<span>`?

```js
angular.module('app', ['ionic']);
```

```css
/* All in one, but not vertically aligned (SAD TITLE) */

.bar-royal .title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Peak";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}



/* Separated, but right in the middle (HAPPY TITLE) */

.bar-positive .title {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.bar-positive .title span {
  font-family: "Peak";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <link href="http://up.cwhit.co/DC2z9d3AYj.css" rel="stylesheet"><!-- custom Peak font -->
  <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.5/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.5/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <ion-pane>

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-calm">
      <h1 class="title">HELVETICA TITLE</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-royal" style="margin-top:50px">
      <h1 class="title">CUSTOM SAD TITLE</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

    <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive" style="margin-top:100px">
      <h1 class="title"><span>CUSTOM HAPPY TITLE</span></h1>
    </ion-header-bar>

  </ion-pane>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How is the `(line-)height` of each element being set?

Comment: @Shaggy `<ion-header-bar>` is 44px in height, then the `h1.title` has a `line-height` of 44px. The `<ion-header-bar>` is also `display: flex;` if that helps.